Brother and sister find a fantasy world and try to help save it
I am looking for a movie from the 70s or 80s about two children that are brother and sister that find a fantasy world and try and help save it with the help of this creature. They need a wizard's help and when they go and find him he is asleep and snoring really loudly. The movie has puppetry. The wizard and all the other characters in the fantasy world are puppets.
Which movie is this?

Is it The Argon Quest (Also called Blizzard Island)?
Brother and sister, Wayne and Tracy, get teleported to the magical Blizzard Island. They meet a creature who to help they must find the giant Argon. Here is some video and the cover art. It is from 1990, but watching the clip I can see how it would be mistaken for an 80s production.
[EDIT: This is an 80s production (See here). It was a 12 episode TV series called Blizzard Island, and then was made into a movie called The Argon Quest in 1990. Interesting to note that it was created by two puppeteers working on Fraggle Rock.]

